# IE8 Javascript document.domain error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dns

I need to change the domain of the document and then set it back again to the original value.

It looks something like this [the page is on domain base.site.com]:

```
function execute ()
{
document.domain = "site.com";

// Access an object that is on another frame, but did the same set of the domain

document.domain = "base.site.com";

// Access an object that is on this page (window.createPopup ())
}
```

The problem is that this works fine on IE6 (I did not test on 7).
But it gives me an error [Invalid argument] when i execute the second document.domain.

Is there any way to "reset" the domain of the document in IE8?

Comment: I don't think it's document.domain thats throwing the error, but a function call somewhere else. Did you test it without other code yet?

Comment: I have done a very simple sample. It is the document.domain that is trowing the error. If i remove the rest of the code and only leave the document.domain the exception still happens.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot set document.domain to a more strict value once you set it to top-domain only.

From the MSDN blog:

> Put simply, once you’ve loosened document.domain, you cannot tighten it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/02/ie8-security-part-vi-beta-2-update.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use script tag  with type `text/cjs`:

```
<script type="text/cjs">
document.domain = '<your domain host value>';
</script>
```