# setting document.domain in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

When I try to set document.domain I get an error in all versions of Internet Explorer that I've tried (IE9, IE11)

I need to have a parent and iframe interact. they are both from the same domain, but different subdomains.

For the parent

```
document.domain = "mydomain.ca";
```

In the Iframe

```
document.domain = "mydomain.ca"
```

When the parent loads, I get the following error in the console:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
```

Everything works in Chrome. Also, I'm running IE9 Compatability Mode (in case that matters)

**UPDATE Nov 16 @ 3:30 Pacific**
Tried this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            document.domain - document.domain;
            alert(document.domain);
            document.domain = "mydomain.ca";
            alert(document.domain);
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

It will give me one alert box with the current domain, but I get the "Invalid argument" error after that. Again, works in Chrome, but not IE9 and not IE11.

Comment: I just created a vanilla html page and tried to set document.domain to the more generic domain and got the same error. This does not appear to be supported in IE9 or IE11, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hey!

SO com:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898253/javascript-document-domain

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657710/ie8-javascript-document-domain-error

Others:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nevermet/archive/2009/07/14/document-domain-can-cause-invalid-argument-error-in-ie8.aspx

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/Web_Browsers/Q_20830303.html

Comment: Yup, I've seen all of those links. Two talk about IE7 and IE8. I don't need this to work in those browsers. I specifically need IE9 and IE11. I will post the test code that I tried and you can see if it works for you.

Comment: I ended up implementing parent.postMessage("my data", "http://sub.mydomain.com"), and setting up a listener on the parent. This may well be a tighter solution anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the issue by using 
`parent.postMessage("My data","http://sub.mydomain.com");` and then setting up a listener on the parent.

this may well be a better solution in the end.